# Start IntelliJ IDEA window maximized

Tags: intellij-idea

Any idea how to start IntelliJ IDEA with it's main window maximized?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

I also tried to create a shortcut with "Run: Maximized" but it didn't work (maybe because of the splash screen?).

Comment: Which OS are you using? IntelliJ seems to remember the window sizing I specify on both Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: @acanby I'm using Windows 7. My point is that I want to start IntelliJ maximized even if it was in a different state before that.

Comment: Indeed, IntelliJ remembers its window state separately for each project. There is no way to control the state when starting the process, other than by patching the .xml files with the stored settings to change the remembered window state.